# Prove all values are zero

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Suppose $\lambda_{1,\cdots,n}\in\Bbb C$ and **for all** $m\in\Bbb N_+$ we have 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^m=0.$$
Prove that all $\lambda_i$ are zero.

Is there any easy approach that doesn't play with algebraic manipulations like symmetric polynomials or Vandermonde determinants? A purely analytical approach would be preferred (e.g. observe the equations as $m$ tends to infinity). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is acceptable to you, as it uses polynomials. It is the most natural way to me. Given any polynomial $p$ with $p(0)=0$, i.e, $p(z)=\sum_{k=1}^ra_kz^k$, we have 
$$\tag1
\sum_{j=1}^np(\lambda_j)=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^ra_k\lambda_j^k=\sum_{k=1}^ra_k\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j^k\right)=0.
$$
In particular, if $\lambda_j\ne0$ for some $j$ we can choose  $p$ with $p(0)=0$ and $p(\lambda_j)=1$ for all $j$ such that $\lambda_j\ne0$. But then the left-hand-side in $(1)$ would be positive, giving a contradiction. So $\lambda_1=\cdots=\lambda_n=0$.

The above also shows that it is enough to have the equalities up to $m=n$, or even less if there are repetitions in the list.

Comment: Thanks. This idea is much better than the analytical approach I would expect.

Comment: Thing is that the condition "for all $m$" is much stronger than needed. One could write the same argument as above but with $r=\infty$, and you get that $\sum_{j=1}^nf(\lambda_j)=0$ for any analytic function.